# How can I check for Google authentication status in my iOS app (Swift 5)

Tags: ios, swift, google-drive-api

When a user authenticates to Google, I want to record the user's status somewhere. When a user clicks on a cell, I want that if the user is authenticated, then I want to send him to another View, and if not, then send him to the authorization page. But I can't do it. I created a flag, but for some reason it only fires after restarting the application.

```
...
protocol SourceViewControllerDelegate{
func requestReloadTable()
}

class SourcesViewController: UIViewController, GIDSignInDelegate  {
...
var isAuthenticationComplete: GIDAuthentication?
...
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: SourceCell.reuseId, for: indexPath) as! SourceCell
        
        cell.sourceViewControllerDelegate = self
....
return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

            tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
            if isAuthenticationComplete != nil {
                let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "GoogleDriveViewController", bundle: nil)
                let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "GoogleDrive") as! GoogleDriveViewController
                navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
            } else {
                GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
            }
    }
...
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!,
              withError error: Error!) {
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        
        guard let authentication = user.authentication else { return }

        isAuthenticationComplete = authentication
    }
...
}

extension SourcesViewController: SourceViewControllerDelegate {
    
    func requestReloadTable() {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

...
class SourceCell: UITableViewCell {
...
var sourceViewControllerDelegate: SourceViewControllerDelegate?
...

    @IBAction func logInLogOutButton(_ sender: Any) {
        print("Log Out button pressed")
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut()
        sourceViewController?.isAuthenticationComplete = nil
        sourceViewControllerDelegate?.requestReloadTable()
    }
}
```

After I click on this button, I can still get to the other screen, but if I restart the application, then when I click on this button I will be taken to the authorization page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
var isAuthenticationComplete: GIDAuthentication?
```

is an instance variable not a saved 1 meaning it's value is nil for the every new object creation of `SourcesViewController`    , you need to save your app state in bool user defaults and check it every open

Save

```
guard let authentication = user.authentication else { return } 
isAuthenticationComplete = authentication
Userdefaults.standard.set(true,forKey:"userAuthorized")
```

Check

```
if Userdefaults.standard.bool(forKey:"userAuthorized") { }
```

Comment: And when I click on the Log Out Button, do I need to delete it from UserDefaults?

Comment: Do I need to reloadData after that?